# Weird whinning noise at exactly 1500 rpm

Tags: honda, noise, fit, jazz

Evidence [at this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtruD_viZhY&feature=youtu.be)

Car is a Honda Fit 2008 GD1 with a new serpentine belt (GATES) and a new tensioner pulley (it's generic).

I got this weird noise at EXACTLY 1500 RPM (no A/C) no matter the gear or if it's during acceleration or deacceleration. It started two weeks after belt/pulley replacement so I suspect is the pulley.

I took the car to the mechanic but it didnt make the sound then. A few days after is back again.

Im going to replace the pulley with a Honda one, but what do you think it could be?

Comment: The whine is from the serpentine belt. Even though it's gates, check for proper alignment, and tensioner has to be OEM. You, yourself diagnosed this case. Why did you shy away from the fix?

Comment: @NumairAidroos - Why do you think it needs to be OEM? Many aftermarket parts are *better than OEM* in quality. To the OP, if you believe it might be the tensioner pulley, squirt just a little bit of WD40 (or any other lubricant) into the bearing (and bearing only) of the thing and see if it changes the sound any. Alternatively, you can use an automotive stethoscope by placing the tip onto the bolt of the tensioner pulley and listen. You'll know this is *exactly* the place where it's coming from if it is from there. Just be careful not to blow your eardrums out.

Comment: Gates and Bando manufactured pulleys hold the serpentine belt well. I've personally had high failure rate with 3rd party tensioners springs. Only specific to Honda Fit/Jazz.